# A const std::function wraps a non-const operator() / mutable lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A
{
    int i;
    void operator()() 
    {
        std::cout << ++i;
    }
};

void test(std::function<void()> const& fun)
{
    fun();
}

int main() {
    const std::function<void()> f{A{}};
    test(f);
    test(f);
}
```

Here, a `const` `std::function` is able to call a non-`const` `operator()`.

Output:

```
12
```

The same happens if I supply a `mutable` lambda e.g. `test([x = 0]() mutable { ++x; });`

How can that be?

Is it normal that a `const std::function` may wrap a mutable functor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it normal that a `const std::function` may wrap a mutable functor?

Unfortunately, yes. `std::function::operator()` is unconditionally qualified as `const` and doesn't care whether or not the wrapped `Callable` is mutated. Some papers attempted to tackle this issue, but AFAIK nothing concrete was yet decided:

- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4348.html
- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0045r1.pdf