# Capturing a lambda in another lambda can violate const qualifiers

Tags: c++, lambda

Consider the following code:

```
int x = 3;
auto f1 = [x]() mutable
{
    return x++;
};
auto f2 = [f1]()
{
    return f1();
};
```

This will not compile, because `f1()` is not const, and `f2` is not declared as mutable. Does this mean that if I have a library function that accepts an arbitrary function argument and captures it in a lambda, I always need to make that lambda mutable, because I don't know what users can pass in? Notably, wrapping `f1` in `std::function` seems to resolve this problem (how?).

Comment: As a side note, that's the case with most of the Rust's functions, [where they explicitly accept `FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) (even though in case of e.g. `fold` it would probably be called with `Fn` most of the time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A const std::function wraps a non-const operator() / mutable lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114936/a-const-stdfunction-wraps-a-non-const-operator-mutable-lambda)

Comment: @rustyx thanks, that answers the last point, but not the whole question.

Comment: A *"lambda violating const qualifiers"* sounds like something out of a sci-fi movie.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Does this mean that if I have a library function that accepts an arbitrary function argument and captures it in a lambda, I always need to make that lambda mutable, because I don't know what users can pass in?

That's a design decision for your library API. You can require client code to pass function objects with a `const`-qualified `operator()` (which is the case for non-`mutable` lambda expressions). If something different is passed, a compiler error is triggered. But if the context might require a function object argument that modifies its state, then yes, you have to make the internal lambda `mutable`.

An alternative would be to dispatch on the ability to invoke `operator()` on a `const`-qualified instance of the given function type. Something along those lines (note that this needs a fix for function objects with both `const` and non-`const` `operator()`, which results in an ambiguity):

```
template <class Fct>
auto wrap(Fct&& f) -> decltype(f(), void())
{
   [fct = std::forward<Fct>(f)]() mutable { fct(); }();
}

template <class Fct>
auto wrap(Fct&& f) -> decltype(std::declval<const Fct&>()(), void())
{
   [fct = std::forward<Fct>(f)]() { fct(); }();
}
```

> Notably, wrapping f1 in std::function seems to resolve this problem (how?).

This is a bug in `std::function` due to its type-erasure and copy semantics. It allows non-`const`-qualified `operator()` to be invoked, which can be verified with such a snippet:

```
const std::function<void()> f = [i = 0]() mutable { ++i; };

f(); // Shouldn't be possible, but unfortunately, it is
```

This is a known issue, it's worth checking out [Titus Winter's complaint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY8tHh2LSX4#t=5m09s) on this.

Answer (score 6):

I'll start by addressing your second question first. `std::function` type erases, and holds a copy of the functor it's initialized with. That means there's a layer of indirection between `std::function::operator()` and the actual functor's `operator()`.

Envision if you will, holding something in your class by pointer. Then you may call a mutating operation on the pointee from a const member function of your class, because it doesn't affect (in a shallow view) the pointer that the class holds. This is a similar situation to what you observed.

As for your first question... "Always" is too strong a word. It depends on your goal.

1. If you want to support self mutating functors easily, then you should capture in a mutable lambda. But beware it may affect the library functions *you* may call now.
2. If you wish to favor non-mutating operations, then a non-mutable lambda. I say "favor" because as we observed, the type system can be "fooled" with an extra level of indirection. So the approach you prefer is only going to be easier to use, not impossible to go around. This is as the sage advice goes, make correct use of your API easy, and incorrect harder.

Comment: Notably, wrapping a passed lambda in `std::ref` provides the level of indirection that allows mutability even in `const` contexts. It also gets around the "functors may be copied around in the implementation" if you are after tracking some state.