# What will happen if I pass a mutable lambda to a function as const reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++17, c++14

What does the code actually do when I pass a mutable lambda as const reference?

Why does not the compiler raise error, is this an undefined operation?

Why f1 and f2 are differnt which f1 uses `std::function<void()>` and f2 uses `auto`?

I found a similar question but I still don't fully understand

[A const std::function wraps a non-const operator() / mutable lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114936/a-const-stdfunction-wraps-a-non-const-operator-mutable-lambda)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void call(std::function<void()> const & cb) {
    cb();
    cb();
}

int main() {
    std::function<void()> f1 = [a = 0] () mutable {
        std::cout << ++a << std::endl;
    };
    call(f1); // prints 1 2
    call(f1); // prints 3 4

    auto f2 = [a = 0] () mutable {
        std::cout << ++a << std::endl;
    };
    call(f2); // prints 1 2
    call(f2); // prints 1 2
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/765endY7c

Comment: Which version of the C++ standard are you asking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In first case both calls of `call(f1)` are using same instance of `std::function<void()>`.

In second case `call(f2);` implicit conversion form lambda to `std::function<void()>` kicks in and respective temporary object is created. So second call uses new copy of temporary object.

[Try transform this code in cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGlvc3RyZWFtPgojaW5jbHVkZSA8ZnVuY3Rpb25hbD4KCnZvaWQgY2FsbChzdGQ6OmZ1bmN0aW9uPHZvaWQoKT4gY29uc3QgJiBjYikgewogICAgY2IoKTsKICAgIGNiKCk7Cn0KCmludCBtYWluKCkgewogICAgc3RkOjpmdW5jdGlvbjx2b2lkKCk%20IGYxID0gW2EgPSAwXSAoKSBtdXRhYmxlIHsKICAgICAgICBzdGQ6OmNvdXQgPDwgKythIDw8IHN0ZDo6ZW5kbDsKICAgIH07CiAgICBjYWxsKGYxKTsgLy8gcHJpbnRzIDEgMgogICAgY2FsbChmMSk7IC8vIHByaW50cyAzIDQKCiAgICBhdXRvIGYyID0gW2EgPSAwXSAoKSBtdXRhYmxlIHsKICAgICAgICBzdGQ6OmNvdXQgPDwgKythIDw8IHN0ZDo6ZW5kbDsKICAgIH07CiAgICBjYWxsKGYyKTsgLy8gcHJpbnRzIDEgMgogICAgY2FsbChmMik7IC8vIHByaW50cyAxIDIKfQo=&std=cpp2a&rev=1.0) to see this with more details.

```cpp
int main()
{
    
  class __lambda_10_32
  {
    public: 
    inline /*constexpr */ void operator()()
    {
      std::cout.operator<<(++a).operator<<(std::endl);
    }
    
    private: 
    int a;
    public: 
    // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_10_32(const __lambda_10_32 &) noexcept = default;
    // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_10_32(__lambda_10_32 &&) noexcept = default;
    __lambda_10_32(const int & _a)
    : a{_a}
    {}
    
  };
  
  std::function<void ()> f1 = std::function<void ()>(__lambda_10_32{0});
  call(f1);
  call(f1);
    
  class __lambda_16_15
  {
    public: 
    inline /*constexpr */ void operator()()
    {
      std::cout.operator<<(++a).operator<<(std::endl);
    }
    
    private: 
    int a;
    public: 
    // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_16_15(const __lambda_16_15 &) noexcept = default;
    // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_16_15(__lambda_16_15 &&) noexcept = default;
    __lambda_16_15(const int & _a)
    : a{_a}
    {}
    
  };
  
  __lambda_16_15 f2 = __lambda_16_15{0};
  call(std::function<void ()>(__lambda_16_15(f2)));
  call(std::function<void ()>(__lambda_16_15(f2)));
  return 0;
}
```